# c# InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I have a cmbPlace(combobox) which it's item filled automatically with System.IO Drives(C:\, D:\, etc). while it's also have validating events. Code below:

```
using System.IO;
public FNamefile()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
    {
        cmbPlace.Items.Add(d.Name);
    }
}

private void FNamefile_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   errorProvider1.ContainerControl = this;
}

private bool ValidatePlace()
{
   bool bStatus = true;
   int m = cmbPlace.SelectedIndex;
   if ((cmbPlace.Items[m]).ToString() == cmbPlace.Text)
   {
       errorProvider1.SetError(cmbPlace, "");
   }
   else if (cmbPlace.Text == "" || (cmbPlace.Items[m]).ToString() != cmbPlace.Text)
   {
       errorProvider1.SetError(cmbPlace, "Please enter a valid location");
       bStatus = false;
   }
   return bStatus;
}
private void cmbPlace_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    ValidatePlace();
    int m = cmbPlace.SelectedIndex;

    if ((cmbPlace.Items[m]).ToString() == cmbPlace.Text)
    {  }
    else
    {
         cmbPlace.Focus();
    }
}
```

The problem is when I tried to test the validating errormessage1 and cmbPlace.Focus() like input 'null' or 'not in index' text, they won't trigger and show error

> InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index

here's the line/code that cause error, in `ValidatePlace` and `cmbPlace_Validating`

```
if ((cmbPlace.Items[m]).ToString() == cmbPlace.Text)
```

Comment: It looks like you are assigning or trying to get a value from an Array with a negative value. That is not possible. Arrays will always start at 0.

Comment: `SelectedIndex` is -1 when nothing is selected. You need to always check for that with `if (cmbPlace.SelectedIndex >= 0)`

Comment: @user3185569 wow that's works, thank you very much!

Comment: @Celcius_Bitz Good News.. Answer posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I posted in the comments, when no item is selected the `SelectedIndex` Property returns -1 which is a invalid index for the accessing an array element by index (using `cmbPlace.Items[m]`). Saying that, you need to check before accessing the selected element:

```
if(cmbPlace.SelectedIndex >= 0)
{
   // do something
}
else
{
  // No item selected, handle that or return
}
```